# after the installation via MacPorts of gcc45, how can I use it to build C language on my Mac?

Tags: c, macos, gcc

The following html link contains all the relevant bash command line records of the installation process. Thank you for help!

## That was a bad question

I didn't use XCode through I know Xcode will make it easier! I use an Air, memory of 4GB currently.
If this won't work easily I probably will quit learning C or run and compile C on Windows. :(

## And XCode stuff, whatever.

Comment: Why not just install Xcode and save yourself a lot of pain?

Comment: You can still use command line tools to compile C if you install Xcode.

Comment: An important follow-up question: The installation of gcc45 +universal seems successful(or not?), why it is still a version of 4.2.1 other than a upgraded version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You command-line output indicates rather clearly that you aren't telling `gcc` what to compile, so it's throwing its hands up in exasperation:

```
$ gcc
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
```

You'll need to specify the file you're compiling. Better yet, use an IDE, like Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

<*Shrug*> What do you want us to say?

Obviousy Macports is trying to build/install gcc but it can't without a compiler.  Yes gcc can be built [without a preexisting compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476439/installing-gcc-on-linux-without-c-compiler), but good luck and why?  Especially when XCode is a [free download](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/), click click let it start and a little while later it's done. At that point as pointed out elsewhere, gcc, g++ will work, but [it's not actually gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535422/os-x-10-9-gcc-links-to-clang) but clang in disguise.

If you want, you can use macports or brew or whatever later if you really want to, but again why? For programs that only work using gcc extensions?  Doubt it. You just want a c/c++ compiler.  If you ever want to do programs for the Mac or IPhone, you need XCode anyway, gcc won't do.

Comment: That is true. I was concerned that XCode would take too much memory while it's working on an Air, and that's all. Thank you for the suggestion.