# Installing make + Installing GCC - without sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've got user account on some strange server running Ubuntu. I do not have root access, so all solutions including `sudo apt-get install <package>` will not work.
For some reason on server there is no `make` nor any C compiler, which prevents it from being usefull in any way.

Without the possibility of using package manager, I've tried to install `make` from the source, but I failed.

My problem is: Installation of `make` requires C compiler (eg. `gcc`), but installing `gcc` from source requires not only `gcc` (which can be worked around - as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476439/installing-gcc-on-linux-without-c-compiler)), but also `make`, which closes the circle.

At this point I gave up and tried to get binary version of `make`, but I couldn't find it. The same was with `gcc` - all I could find were tarballs containing the source.

It's the list of possible solutions, I can think of:

1. Page with binary of `make`.
2. Page with working binary of `gcc` or any other C compiler.
3. Or some way to install one of these from the source, with earlier listed restrictions.
4. Some other way?

Comment: Do you have a C compiler at all?

Comment: Consider installing a gcc binary.

Comment: No - if i had any, there wouldn't be problem with installation of make.

Comment: It#s tricky. Did you try the options described in this, admittedly quite old, post here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access ?

Comment: Maybe the owners of the strange server won't be happy with you for putting development tools on their server — they may have deliberately ensured there was no development code on it.  There are bound to be precompiled versions of the tools available.  Failing that, create yourself a virtual machine image on a machine of your own with the correct version of Ubuntu, and install what you need on there, and then compile and install materials on the VM and copy to the server for installation.

Comment: Also note that current versions of GCC require G++ or other standard C++ compiler to bootstrap — not just a C compiler any more.

Comment: I see that TCC (http://www.tinycc.org/) is in the Ubuntu repository. It needs only libc-dev which is just the headers of the installed LibC version. If TCC compiles `make` or even `GCC` is a different question.

Comment: You can get `gcc` from  [www.mingw.org](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: I don't have time to research further, but one time I built all of gcc just running `make bootstrap` from the gcc src dir. It might still work. Good luck.

Comment: Bring binaries to that host. You may setup virtual environment on your side with the same version of OS and copy binaries from it to remote server. (Since you have no root access, under **binaries** I can consider BuildRoot in your home)

Comment: This is not about programming within the rules of this site, but general software/system management.

Comment: @shellter: How would that work if you don't have `make` available?

Comment: Have you contacted the admin of the server to explain what it is you're trying to do? Technical solutions to social problems are bad in general.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)